# Add new rows from categorical values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

This is my dataframe

```
year   state    sex   age   population  deaths
-----------------------------------------------
1970   Cal      Male    12     134         45
1970   Cal      Female  12     100         20
1980   Pen      Male    13     200         10
1980   Pen      Female  13     150         50
```

What I want to do is add the number of deaths and population for each year, and state based on the column sex. And create a new row called **Total**, with the sum of these values.

I would like to have this:

For each year, example (1970,1980,1990...2050) I have a column called **age** from 0 to 100. With the number of deaths and population for Male and Female.
I want to add the number of population and death for each year,state and age. (keeping the value of age)

I mean I want a third row with the add of Femlaes and Males (Total) and keep the age and year.

```
    year   state    sex   age   population     deaths
-----------------------------------------------
1970       Cal      Male       12     134         45
1970       Cal      Female     12     100         20
1970       Cal      Total      12     234         65
1980       Pen      Male       13     200         10
1980       Pen      Female     13     150         50
1980       Pen      Total      13     350         60
```

I tried with this line

```
df_1 <- setDT(df)[,rbind(.SD,c(.(sex = "Total"),colSums(.SD[,-1]))),state,.SDcols = c("sex",    "population", "deaths", "year", "age")]
```

But is not giving me the right result.
How can I do this?

Comment: You might use group_by() and other functions from dplyr. Can you share sample data using dput()? It's hard to help with what you provided. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. adorn_totals

```
library(purrr)
library(janitor)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)


df %>% 
  dplyr::select(sex, everything()) %>%
  dplyr::group_split(year, state, age) %>% 
  purrr::map_dfr(janitor::adorn_totals) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(across(c(year, state, age), ~ ifelse(sex == "Total", NA, .))) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(everything(), .direction = "down") %>% 
  dplyr::select(year, state, everything())
```

FYI, `across` is from the `dplyr` library.

**Output**

```
year state    sex age population deaths
 1970   Cal   Male  12        134     45
 1970   Cal Female  12        100     20
 1970   Cal  Total  12        234     65
 1980   Pen   Male  13        200     10
 1980   Pen Female  13        150     50
 1980   Pen  Total  13        350     60
```

---

**How it works**

1. The first `select` statement is to accommodate the behavior of `janitor::adorn_totals`, which puts the "Total" label in the first column. So this puts `sex` as the first column.
2. `group_split` splits the dataframe into a list of dataframes by same `year`, `state`, and `age`.
3. `purrr::map_dfr` will map `janitor::adorn_totals` over each dataframe in the list, which essentially is creating subtotals, and then row binds back into one dataframe, hence the `r` in `dfr`.
4. The remainder of the pipes are to format the data how you requested. So that the `year`, `state`, and `age` columns will have the same value in the "Total" row. The last `select` reorders everything back to the original order.

---

### 2. Pivot

Alternatively, since `janitor::adorn_totals` is a bit buggy you can do this using some pivots to create the exact same output:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = c(year, state, age),
                     names_from = sex, 
                     values_from = population:deaths) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(population_Total = rowSums(across(starts_with("population"))),
                deaths_Total = rowSums(across(starts_with("deaths")))) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = contains("_"), 
                      names_to = c(".value", "sex"),
                      names_pattern = c("(.*)_(.*)$"))
```

FYI, `across`, `contains`, and `starts_with` are exported or from the `dplyr` library.

---

**How it works**

1. `pivot_wider` re-orients the data so there is one row per `year`, `state`, and `age`. New columns are created appending `sex` to the end of the pivoted columns, which are `population` and `deaths` in this case. This creates columns `population_Male`, `population_Female`, `deaths_Male`, and so on.
2. We then sum across rows using `tidyselect` syntax to sum all the rows starting with "population" and likewise for "deaths", storing them in appropriately named columns appended with "_Total".
3. The final pivot maintains the `year`, `state`, and `age` as the ID columns. It pivots all columns with an underscore: `population_Male`, `population_Female`, `population_Total`, etc. Using regular expressions the column *names* are parsed by the underscore: `population_Total` is parsed into the strings `population` and `Total`. The former becomes a column name storing values, the latter is a value stored in a column called "sex".

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much forr the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Generally the pattern is to store summary variables like this in a new table, which maintains the link between the rows of your data frame and the observations of your original data (see the [Tidy Data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) chapter of *R for Data Science*). You can do this with a combination of dplyr's `group_by()` and `summarise()` functions:

```r
library("dplyr")

df <- readr::read_table("
year   state    sex     age    population  deaths
1970   Cal      Male    12     134         45
1970   Cal      Female  12     100         20
1980   Pen      Male    13     200         10
1980   Pen      Female  13     150         50
")

df %>% 
  group_by(year, state, age) %>% 
  summarise(population = sum(population),
            deaths = sum(deaths),
            .groups = "drop") ->
  df_total
  

df_total
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>    year state   age population deaths
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1  1970 Cal      12        234     65
#> 2  1980 Pen      13        350     60
```

If you really want this in the original data table, you can simply use `mutate()` to add a `sex` column and `bind_rows()` the two back together:

```r
df_total <- mutate(df_total, sex = "Total")

bind_rows(df, df_total) %>% 
  arrange(year, state, sex)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>    year state sex      age population deaths
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1  1970 Cal   Female    12        100     20
#> 2  1970 Cal   Male      12        134     45
#> 3  1970 Cal   Total     12        234     65
#> 4  1980 Pen   Female    13        150     50
#> 5  1980 Pen   Male      13        200     10
#> 6  1980 Pen   Total     13        350     60
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to scale your solution in my real data set but unfortunately I am getting the same number of deaths and population for all of my rows no matter the age. I will update my question

Comment: In your original question, you said you only wanted the totals by state and sex (and there is only one age per group in your example data). If you want it also by age, you simply need to add age to the `group_by()` (and omit it from the first `mutate()`). I've changed the code above accordingly.